# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource in react js with axios get method

Tags: reactjs

i'm using axios in react js

```
state = {
posts: []
```

};

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://doamin.com/api/v1/categories`)
      .then(res => {
        const posts = res.data;
        this.setState({ posts });
      })
  };
```

i got error

```
    Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://doamin.com/api/v1/categories' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
doamin.com/api/v1/categories:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84)
```

Please Fixed my issue .
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is an issue related to the API side. Please check the CORS configuration on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have check your request is there is no issue with your api.
Please add some code in your server side  .htaccess file  and check it

```
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
```